# Update to 4.4.1 breaks my pagination

Tags: pagination, updates

I recently updated to 4.4.1 and I noticed my pagination was screwed up. I can't go to page 2 or further because all it does is going back to the home page so I had to go back to a previous version in order to fix it. My latest backup was a 4.1.2 version and there it works fine. I don't know at what exact version it breaks but I'm pretty sure is 4.4 or so.

How can I fix this so I can update without breaking my pagination?

Comment: This is probably a static front page. There is a bug in v4.4.1 which causes a failure on pagination on static front pages. It will be fixed in v 4.4.2

Comment: Anything I can do in the mean time?

Comment: Yes, check the current [patch here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35344)

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending content with <!--nextpage--> broken in 4.4](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211565/appending-content-with-nextpage-broken-in-4-4)

Comment: @denis.stoyanov the post you marked as duplicate is not related. I first thought that is was, but the issue with single post pages is different ;-). If you wish, you can always post what I have said in comments as an answer with the link to the relevant trac ticket ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen I see. My bad then. I thought that was similar. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: 4.4.2 just came out and I am still having the same problem as OP

Comment: Just cleaning up the unanswered questions list, @PieterGoosen I know you might not be around anymore but if you see this, would you like to add an answer with your solution as above?

Comment: @moodyjive If you're still having the same problem it's likely caused by something else. Feel free to post a new question going through the issue you're experiencing.