# Paged Single Post doesn't redirect to the main url after Removing Pagination

Tags: functions, pagination, redirect

I used

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

([Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Page-Links)) to paginate (split) a few single posts. Now i removed all the nextpage html parts from the posts. everthing looks fine. Unfortunately the old urls like

```
sample.com/tipps-for-me/2

sample.com/tipps-for-me/3

sample.com/tipps-for-me/4
```

...

do not redirect to the main url `sample.com/tipps-for-me`. Instead, it shows exactly the same (whole) content of the main url (`sample.com/tipps-for-me`) when im watching `sample.com/tipps-for-me/2`, `sample.com/tipps-for-me/3`, `sample.com/tipps-for-me/4` and so on.

**I do not use any redirect Plugin or redirect function anywhere. Any idea how to fix this problem?**

Comment: This is not handled in core if I recall correctly - only pagination checks when the content contains `<!--nextpage-->`. This means that the `content_pagination` filter doesn't work as expected. @PieterGoosen submitted a ticket recently [#35562](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35562) on a somewhat related subject. The part of the core that handles the content pagination will need some further adjustments to address this.

Comment: Short answer, just don't worry about it - users still get your content, and Google won't dupe it thanks to the `<link rel="canonical" />` tag

Comment: @birgire - thx for the quick comment. @ TheDeadMedic - im using the yoast SEO plugin, and all canonical links are fine - but google shows in the webmaster console duplicate meta description... This was the reason why i removed the <!--nextpage--> tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## EDIT

I have played around with a possible solution to your issue. We can try the following

- Add our own action to `template_redirect` where we do the following

  - Check that the current request is a paged single post page and that we do not have the `<!--nextpage-->` tag in the post content.
  - If everything checks out in our condition, we will do a manual redirect to the first page of the post

Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'template_redirect', function()
{
    if (    is_single() 
         && false === strpos( get_queried_object()->post_content, '<!--nextpage-->' )
         && get_query_var('page') 
    ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_queried_object_id() ) );
        die;
    }
});
```

### IMPORTANT NOTES

This will also redirect the current paged single post page to the first page even if we make use of the `content_pagination` filter. The code only takes the `<!--nextpage-->` tag into consideration, so you will need to make sure that you will not paginate a single post with any other method than the `<!--nextpage-->` tag

**END OF EDIT**

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

I'm pretty sure that this will need a lot of investigation and a lot of testing, swearing and rewriting of code to make this work.

Unfortunately when you have a URL like `sample.com/tipps-for-me/4`, WordPress will and has always as far as I remember from meeting WordPress in version 3.3.1, accepted that URL structure as valid, even when a post only has one page, so this is nothing new.

WordPress 4.4 saw the new `content_pagination` filter being added and the following piece of code to `redirect_canonical`

```
$next = '<!--nextpage-->';
if ( $p && false !== strpos( $p->post_content, $next ) && ! empty( $this->query_vars['page'] ) ) {
    $page = trim( $this->query_vars['page'], '/' );
    $success = (int) $page <= ( substr_count( $p->post_content, $next ) + 1 );
}
```

What this successfully does is, if you have the `<!--nextpage-->` tag in a post, every page after the last page after the `<!--nextpage-->` tag will 404 and redirect back to the first page. This is really the only time you will have success with URL's like `sample.com/tipps-for-me/4` when that page is a page after the last page after the `<!--nextpage-->` tag. If we remove the `<!--nextpage-->` tag, we can still successfully enter any URL without being redirected as pre WordPress 4.4

This piece of code however creates other issues which I have raised (*a still open unresolved*) [trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35562) for, and between me and @birgire we handled the issue in the following question a week or two ago

- [Appending content with <!--nextpage--> broken in 4.4](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/211565/31545)

I have asked in the mentioned trac ticket to remove the code from `redirect_canonical()` to avoid the new issues it created until we find a solid solution to handle pagination on single posts.

I think what really makes this very difficult now is the new `content_pagination` filter, as we will need to find a way to handle pages correctly that are added via the filter with and without the `<!--nextpage-->` tag. Another issue is that pre WordPress 4.4, people used the `the_post` filter to add additional page to a single post in addition to the `<!--nextpage-->` tag, so this adds even more issues to handle in such a way that we do not break those sites which are still relying on older valid methods

### TO CONCLUDE

There will most certainly not be a solution to this in the near future. Like many other bugs that exists like all posts being returned by `WP_Query` on an invalid term or taxonomy or on an empty search submission or over sanitizing term names in a `tax_query`, there really is no concrete solution to fix these issues. My bet is that some of these issue will never be fixed and will remain till the end of days.

From SEO point of view, it does not have any affect, so it is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. Hopefully this problem will be solved. In the google webmaster console, my paginated posts marked as content with duplicated meta description. This was the reason why i removed the  <!--nextpage--> tag. As mentioned before, the links are still there and all the urls show the same content. Hopefully google will remove this urls from the index...

Comment: I'm almost sure that if it ever is going to be solved, it will not be this year ;-)

Comment: can you help me out with the following problem to (no help so far) - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216772/add-multiple-filter-using-preg-replace-callback-to-image-tags-in-single-post

Comment: I have a possible workaround which you can test for your issue here, I tested it and it works on my side on initial test. Be sure to try it out, and lets get this issue marked as solved ;-)